# MySQL stored function: Working with a comma-separated string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Start dates are stored in a comma-separated string in MySQL. I want a stored function to get the earliest start date from the CSV string

EG:

The string:    `2018-04-16,2018-10-08,2018-11-15`

The desired result:  `2018-04-16`

Comment: Please post the code for your stored function so we can help you fix the issue.

Comment: I'm thinking something like this:

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION MIN_DATE_FROM_CSV(str VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
DECLARE mindate VARCHAR(12)
SET mindate = 0

//get first date (up to first comma)
mindate = SUBSTRING('str',0,LOCATE(',',str))

//the remainder of str(without the first comma)
str = SUBSTRING('str',(LOCATE(',',str)+1))



WHILE LENGTH(str) > 0


//get first date (up to first comma)
x = SUBSTRING('str',0,LOCATE(',',str))


IF x <= mindate  THEN

mindate = x
//the remainder of str(without the comma)
str = SUBSTRING('str',(LOCATE(',',str)+1))

END IF 


END WHILE
RETURN mindate

END $$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date strings always have exactly three dates, then the following should work:

```
SELECT
    LEAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dates, ',', 1),
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dates, ',', -2), ',', 1),
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(dates, ',', -1)) AS least_date
FROM yourTable;

2018-04-16
```

### Demo

*However*, your current table has seriously poor design if you are storing dates as CSV strings.  Instead, you should be storing each date in a separate record.  Then, you could easily use the `MIN` function, possibly with `GROUP BY`, to get the answer you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No there won't always be 3 dates. That's why I thought a stored function might provide a solution. I agree about the bad design but sometimes you just have to work with what you are given.

Comment: I don't see any point in writing a proc.  Just fix your data model.  Anyway, all operations will be difficult, including insertion and especially updating.

Comment: Tim, if I can get this to work, It will save a lot of time. I'm most of the way there - just not sure of the MYSql syntax

Answer (score 0):

This is close. - still some syntax errors:

```
CREATE FUNCTION min_date_from_csv(str VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(12)
BEGIN
DECLARE mindate VARCHAR(12);
DECLARE x VARCHAR(12);
SET mindate = 0;
SET x = 0;


IF LOCATE(',',str)>0 THEN
   mindate = SUBSTRING(str,0,(LOCATE(',',str)));
   str = SUBSTRING(str,(LOCATE(',',str)));
   TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM str);
ELSE
   mindate = str;
END IF; 


WHILE LOCATE(',',str)>0
   x = SUBSTRING(str,0,(LOCATE(',',str)));
   IF x <= mindate  THEN
      mindate = x;
   END IF;

   str = SUBSTRING(str,(LOCATE(',',str)));
   TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM str);
END WHILE;
RETURN mindate;
```